# How to implement angularjs routing with cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement angularjs routing with cshtml but i am unable to accomplish it. Can someone look into this ? what i am doing wrong.

index.cshtml:

```
<a href="#/route1">Route 1</a>
```

productmodule.js

```
var app = angular.module("productmodule", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
                 when('/route1', {
                     templateUrl: '/Product/Details',
                     controller: 'ProductController'
                 }).
                 otherwise({
                     redirectTo: '/'
                 });
  }]);
```

Details.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view=""></div>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

ProductController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace webapp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Product/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

What i wanted to achieve is when I click the Route 1 link from ( index.cshtml) I should be able to navigate to Details.cshtml

Comment: Is there anything in the console? Did you add the correct ng-app to your main page?

Comment: Btw, I think your details cshtml page should be a template that gets loaded into an ng-view. What url are you browsing to?

Comment: My understanding here is your mixing server technology and client side technology here.  There Angular controller in the route provider is a client side controller, and as such there is no link between the server controller and clicking that link?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly. You state that "It doesn't work", but what is "It"?

Answer (score 0):

When you click your anchor tag it's going to send a request to the server (i.e. the MVC routing) for the resource at "/". Being that you didn't specify a controller or action it will look for the default, which is Home/Index (assuming you haven't changed the default route configuration). Look for code similar to the following in your .NET project.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

If you want Product/Index to be the default you can change "Home" to "Product". Alternatively you can change your anchor tag to specify the controller.

```
<a href="Product#/route1">Route 1</a>
```

Either way, MVC will deliver the Index view and at that point Angular's routing will take over, examine the "#/route1" and load the appropriate ng-view.

Comment: I changed the default route from Home to Product. When I click the Route 1 link , i was expecting it to go to details page but I am unable to accomplish that.

Comment: Without knowing what your route(s) look like and what is actually happening I can't even begin to guess what might be wrong. "Unable to accomplish that" isn't really much to go on. You might be getting a 401, 403, 404, 500... When you get a bug report don't you expect more than, "It don't work?"